# woocommerce up-sells orderby date

Tags: php, woocommerce

trying to edit WoCommerce up-sells.php file to have it order Up-Sells by date (desc)

```
$args = array(
'post_type'           => 'product',
'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
'no_found_rows'       => 1,
'posts_per_page'      => $posts_per_page,
'orderby'             => 'date',
'order'               => 'desc',
'post__in'            => $upsells,
'post__not_in'        => array( $product->id ),
'meta_query'          => $meta_query
);
```

but doesn't seem to work properly. any ideas?

update: actually, this solution works.

Comment: Should work fine, which page are you checking it on? Depending on the theme, the up-sells usually show on the single product page.

Comment: yep.. you're right, it does work fine. forgot about clearing cache, so that's why I didn't saw any change.